# What is the best way to integrate custom Modernizr build into an Angular project?

Tags: angular, webpack, modernizr

I want to integrate a custom Modernizr build into my Angular project for feature detection.
I found this [Webpack Modernizr loader on GitHub](https://github.com/peerigon/modernizr-loader), but I don't know how to integrate it into my project.

I put the following code into a `.modernizrrc` file in my project root but how do I actually call it?

```
{
  "minify": true,
  "options": [
    "setClasses"
  ],
  "feature-detects": [
    "test/css/vwunit"
  ]
}
```

There is this code in the `README` file, but I don't know where to put it.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc.js$/,
        use: [ 'modernizr-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc(\.json)?$/,
        use: [ 'modernizr-loader', 'json-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/.modernizrrc")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem. You can include a partial webpack config using [ngx-build-plus](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/ngx-build-plus).

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc.js$/,
        use: [ 'modernizr-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.modernizrrc(\.json)?$/,
        use: [ 'modernizr-loader', 'json-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      modernizr$: path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/.modernizrrc")
    }
  }
}
```